# Django access request.user in class based view

Tags: python, django

I'm currently working on the following issue: The user can access the page `test.com/BlogPostTitle`. Where `BlogPostTitle` is a slug. If a Blog post with the fitting title exists, Django should render the DetailView of said blog post. If it doesn't exist, Django should render a form to create a blog post.

This works so far:

```
class EntryDetail(DetailView): # Displays blog entry, if it exists
    model = Blog
    slug_field = 'title'
    template_name = 'app/entry.html'    

class EntryForm(FormView): # Displays form, if entry 404s
    template_name = 'app/create.html'
    form_class = EntryForm
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(EntryForm, self).form_valid(form)

class EntryDisplay(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            view = EntryDetail.as_view()
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            if check_user_editor(self.request.user) == True: # Fails here
                view = EntryForm.as_view()
                return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                pass
```

Now, only users who are in the group "editor" should be able to see the form/create a post:

```
def check_user_editor(user):
    if user:
        return user.groups.filter(name="editor").exists() # Returns true, if user in editor group
    else:
        return False⋅
```

As you can see, I've implemented the function in the `EntryDisplay`, however, Django errors `'User' object is not iterable`.

I'm guessing I've to work with `SingleObjectMixin`, but I haven't quite understood the docs on that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Full traceback:

Traceback:

```
File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get_object
  53.             obj = queryset.get()

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  385.                 self.model._meta.object_name

During handling of the above exception (Blog matching query does not exist.), another exception occurred:

File "/home/django/mediwiki/mediwiki/views.py" in get
  68.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get
  115.         self.object = self.get_object()

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/detail.py" in get_object
  56.                           {'verbose_name': queryset.model._meta.verbose_name})

During handling of the above exception (No blog found matching the query), another exception occurred:

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/django/mediwiki/mediwiki/views.py" in get
  74.                 view = HttpResponse(request.user)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/http/response.py" in __init__
  293.         self.content = content

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/http/response.py" in content
  319.             content = b''.join(self.make_bytes(chunk) for chunk in value)

File "/home/django/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  235.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: TypeError at /test
Exception Value: 'User' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full traceback.

Comment: @knbk Yes, ofcourse. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in line 74 in `mediwiki.views`:

```
view = HttpResponse(request.user)
```

`HttpResponse` expects a string or an iterable. Since `request.user` is not a string, it tries to use it as an iterable, which fails.

I can't say much without the actual code. If in fact you *want* to send just a string representation of the user as the response, you need to cast is to a string:

```
view = HttpResponse(str(request.user))
```

Comment: Ah, bollocks! Turns out, what was added for debug purposes was actually causing a bug itself. I wanted to check whether `request.user` was even callable and forgot to string it. Good catch, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Is the error occurred at template rendering? If so I wonder you've make iter over attributes on single `User` object. I think you may need `user.values()`.

BTW, `check_user_editor` should be simpler:

```
def check_user_editor(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name="editor").exists()
```